# Android: How to draw multiple routes from source to destination on map?

Tags: android, api, google-maps, routes, direction

I am able to draw single route using polyline between two geo points on android map v2. But i don't know how to draw multiple routes from source to destination I tried to add "alternatives=true" but still only getting one route on map. Someone please help me out how to do this as i do so much research on web, but still can't able to find any easy understandable solution for this.

GoogleDirection.java

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class GoogleDirection {


public GoogleDirection(Context context) { 
    mContext = context;
}


public String request(LatLng start, LatLng end, String mode) {
    final String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?"
            + "origin=" + start.latitude + "," + start.longitude  
            + "&destination=" + end.latitude + "," + end.longitude 
            + "&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=" + mode + "alternatives=true";

    if(isLogging)
        Log.i("GoogleDirection", "URL : " + url);
    new RequestTask().execute(new String[]{ url });
    return url;
}

private class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Document> {
    protected Document doInBackground(String... url) {
        try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url[0]);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
            InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
            DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            return builder.parse(in);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Document doc) {
        super.onPostExecute(doc);
        if(mDirectionListener != null)
            mDirectionListener.onResponse(getStatus(doc), doc, GoogleDirection.this);
    }

    private String getStatus(Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("status");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        if(isLogging)
            Log.i("GoogleDirection", "Status : " + node1.getTextContent());
        return node1.getTextContent();
    }
}

public void setLogging(boolean state) {
    isLogging = state;
}

public String getStatus(Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("status");
    Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
    if(isLogging)
        Log.i("GoogleDirection", "Status : " + node1.getTextContent());
    return node1.getTextContent();
}

public String[] getDurationText(Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("duration");
    String[] arr_str = new String[nl1.getLength() - 1];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < nl1.getLength() - 1 ; i++) {
        Node node1 = nl1.item(i);
        NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
        Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "text"));
        arr_str[i] = node2.getTextContent();
        if(isLogging)
            Log.i("GoogleDirection", "DurationText : " + node2.getTextContent());
    }
    return arr_str;
}

public int[] getDurationValue(Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("duration");
    int[] arr_int = new int[nl1.getLength() - 1];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < nl1.getLength() - 1 ; i++) {
        Node node1 = nl1.item(i);
        NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
        Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "value"));
        arr_int[i] = Integer.parseInt(node2.getTextContent());
        if(isLogging)
            Log.i("GoogleDirection", "Duration : " + node2.getTextContent());
    }
    return arr_int;
}

public String getTotalDurationText(Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("duration");
    Node node1 = nl1.item(nl1.getLength() - 1);
    NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
    Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "text"));
    if(isLogging)
        Log.i("GoogleDirection", "TotalDuration : " + node2.getTextContent());
    return node2.getTextContent();
}

public int getTotalDurationValue(Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("duration");
    Node node1 = nl1.item(nl1.getLength() - 1);
    NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
    Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "value"));
    if(isLogging)
        Log.i("GoogleDirection", "TotalDuration : " + node2.getTextContent());
    return Integer.parseInt(node2.getTextContent());
}

public String[] getDistanceText(Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("distance");
    String[] arr_str = new String[nl1.getLength() - 1];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < nl1.getLength() - 1 ; i++) {
        Node node1 = nl1.item(i);
        NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
        Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "text"));
        arr_str[i] = node2.getTextContent();
        if(isLogging)
            Log.i("GoogleDirection", "DurationText : " + node2.getTextContent());
    }
    return arr_str;
}

public int[] getDistanceValue(Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("distance");
    int[] arr_int = new int[nl1.getLength() - 1];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < nl1.getLength() - 1 ; i++) {
        Node node1 = nl1.item(i);
        NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
        Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "value"));
        arr_int[i] = Integer.parseInt(node2.getTextContent());
        if(isLogging)
            Log.i("GoogleDirection", "Duration : " + node2.getTextContent());
    }
    return arr_int;
}

public String getTotalDistanceText(Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("distance");
    Node node1 = nl1.item(nl1.getLength() - 1);
    NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
    Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "text"));
    if(isLogging)
        Log.i("GoogleDirection", "TotalDuration : " + node2.getTextContent());
    return node2.getTextContent();
}

public int getTotalDistanceValue(Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("distance");
    Node node1 = nl1.item(nl1.getLength() - 1);
    NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
    Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "value"));
    if(isLogging)
        Log.i("GoogleDirection", "TotalDuration : " + node2.getTextContent());
    return Integer.parseInt(node2.getTextContent());
}

public String getStartAddress(Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("start_address");
    Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
    if(isLogging)
        Log.i("GoogleDirection", "StartAddress : " + node1.getTextContent());
    return node1.getTextContent();
}

public String getEndAddress(Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("end_address");
    Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
    if(isLogging)
        Log.i("GoogleDirection", "StartAddress : " + node1.getTextContent());
    return node1.getTextContent();
}

public String getCopyRights(Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("copyrights");
    Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
    if(isLogging)
        Log.i("GoogleDirection", "CopyRights : " + node1.getTextContent());
    return node1.getTextContent();
}

public ArrayList<LatLng> getDirection(Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1, nl2, nl3;
    ArrayList<LatLng> listGeopoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("step");
    if (nl1.getLength() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nl1.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node1 = nl1.item(i);
            nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();

            Node locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "start_location"));
            nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
            Node latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lat"));
            double lat = Double.parseDouble(latNode.getTextContent());
            Node lngNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lng"));
            double lng = Double.parseDouble(lngNode.getTextContent());
            listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));

            locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "polyline"));
            nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
            latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "points"));
            ArrayList<LatLng> arr = decodePoly(latNode.getTextContent());
            for(int j = 0 ; j < arr.size() ; j++) {
                listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(arr.get(j).latitude
                        , arr.get(j).longitude));
            }

            locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "end_location"));
            nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
            latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lat"));
            lat = Double.parseDouble(latNode.getTextContent());
            lngNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lng"));
            lng = Double.parseDouble(lngNode.getTextContent());
            listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));
        }
    }

    return listGeopoints;
}

public ArrayList<LatLng> getSection(Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1, nl2, nl3;
    ArrayList<LatLng> listGeopoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("step");
    if (nl1.getLength() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nl1.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node1 = nl1.item(i);
            nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();

            Node locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "end_location"));
            nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
            Node latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lat"));
            double lat = Double.parseDouble(latNode.getTextContent());
            Node lngNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lng"));
            double lng = Double.parseDouble(lngNode.getTextContent());
            listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));
        }
    }

    return listGeopoints;
}

public PolylineOptions getPolyline(Document doc, int width, int color) {
    ArrayList<LatLng> arr_pos = getDirection(doc);
    PolylineOptions rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(dpToPx(width)).color(color);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < arr_pos.size() ; i++)        
        rectLine.add(arr_pos.get(i));
    return rectLine;
}

private int getNodeIndex(NodeList nl, String nodename) {
    for(int i = 0 ; i < nl.getLength() ; i++) {
        if(nl.item(i).getNodeName().equals(nodename))
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

private ArrayList<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {
    ArrayList<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
    int lat = 0, lng = 0;
    while (index < len) {
        int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lat += dlat;
        shift = 0;
        result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lng += dlng;

        LatLng position = new LatLng((double)lat / 1E5, (double)lng / 1E5);
        poly.add(position);
    }
    return poly;
}

private int dpToPx(int dp) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int px = Math.round(dp * (displayMetrics.xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));       
    return px;
}

public void setOnDirectionResponseListener(OnDirectionResponseListener listener) {
    mDirectionListener = listener;
}

public void setOnAnimateListener(OnAnimateListener listener) {
    mAnimateListener = listener;
}

public interface OnDirectionResponseListener {
    public void onResponse(String status, Document doc, GoogleDirection gd);
}

public interface OnAnimateListener {
    public void onFinish();
    public void onStart();
    public void onProgress(int progress, int total);
}

public void animateDirection(GoogleMap gm, ArrayList<LatLng> direction, int speed
        , boolean cameraLock, boolean isCameraTilt, boolean isCameraZoom
        , boolean drawMarker, MarkerOptions mo, boolean flatMarker
        , boolean drawLine, PolylineOptions po) {
    if(direction.size() > 1) {
        isAnimated = true;
        animatePositionList = direction;
        animateSpeed = speed;
        this.drawMarker = drawMarker;
        this.drawLine = drawLine;
        this.flatMarker = flatMarker;
        this.isCameraTilt = isCameraTilt;
        this.isCameraZoom = isCameraZoom;
        step = 0;
        this.cameraLock = cameraLock;
        this.gm = gm;

        setCameraUpdateSpeed(speed);

        beginPosition = animatePositionList.get(step);
        endPosition = animatePositionList.get(step + 1);
        animateMarkerPosition = beginPosition;

        if(mAnimateListener != null)
            mAnimateListener.onProgress(step, animatePositionList.size());

        if(cameraLock) {
            float bearing = getBearing(beginPosition, endPosition);
            CameraPosition.Builder cameraBuilder = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(animateMarkerPosition).bearing(bearing);

            if(isCameraTilt) 
                cameraBuilder.tilt(90);
            else 
                cameraBuilder.tilt(gm.getCameraPosition().tilt);

            if(isCameraZoom) 
                cameraBuilder.zoom(zoom);
            else 
                cameraBuilder.zoom(gm.getCameraPosition().zoom);

            CameraPosition cameraPosition = cameraBuilder.build();
            gm.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
        }

        if(drawMarker) {
            if(mo != null)
                animateMarker = gm.addMarker(mo.position(beginPosition));
            else 
                animateMarker = gm.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(beginPosition));

            if(flatMarker) {
                animateMarker.setFlat(true);

                float rotation = getBearing(animateMarkerPosition, endPosition) + 180;
                animateMarker.setRotation(rotation);
            }
        }


        if(drawLine) {
            if(po != null) 
                animateLine = gm.addPolyline(po.add(beginPosition)
                        .add(beginPosition).add(endPosition)
                        .width(dpToPx((int)po.getWidth())));
            else 
                animateLine = gm.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                        .width(dpToPx(5)));
        }

        new Handler().postDelayed(r, speed);
        if(mAnimateListener != null)
            mAnimateListener.onStart();
    }
}

public void cancelAnimated() {
    isAnimated = false;
}

public boolean isAnimated() {
    return isAnimated;
}

private Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        animateMarkerPosition = getNewPosition(animateMarkerPosition, endPosition);

        if(drawMarker)
            animateMarker.setPosition(animateMarkerPosition);


        if(drawLine) {
            List<LatLng> points = animateLine.getPoints();
            points.add(animateMarkerPosition);
            animateLine.setPoints(points);
        }

        if((animateMarkerPosition.latitude == endPosition.latitude 
                && animateMarkerPosition.longitude == endPosition.longitude)) {
            if(step == animatePositionList.size() - 2) {
                isAnimated = false;
                totalAnimateDistance = 0;
                if(mAnimateListener != null)
                    mAnimateListener.onFinish();
            } else {
                step++;
                beginPosition = animatePositionList.get(step);
                endPosition = animatePositionList.get(step + 1);
                animateMarkerPosition = beginPosition;

                if(flatMarker && step + 3 < animatePositionList.size() - 1) {
                    float rotation = getBearing(animateMarkerPosition, animatePositionList.get(step + 3)) + 180;
                    animateMarker.setRotation(rotation);
                }

                if(mAnimateListener != null)
                    mAnimateListener.onProgress(step, animatePositionList.size());
            }
        }

        if(cameraLock && (totalAnimateDistance > animateCamera || !isAnimated)) {
            totalAnimateDistance = 0;
            float bearing = getBearing(beginPosition, endPosition);
            CameraPosition.Builder cameraBuilder = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(animateMarkerPosition).bearing(bearing);

            if(isCameraTilt) 
                cameraBuilder.tilt(90);
            else 
                cameraBuilder.tilt(gm.getCameraPosition().tilt);

            if(isCameraZoom) 
                cameraBuilder.zoom(zoom);
            else 
                cameraBuilder.zoom(gm.getCameraPosition().zoom);

            CameraPosition cameraPosition = cameraBuilder.build();
            gm.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

        }

        if(isAnimated) {
            new Handler().postDelayed(r, animateSpeed);
        }
    }
};

public Marker getAnimateMarker() {
    return animateMarker;
}

public Polyline getAnimatePolyline() {
    return animateLine;
}

private LatLng getNewPosition(LatLng begin, LatLng end) {
    double lat = Math.abs(begin.latitude - end.latitude); 
    double lng = Math.abs(begin.longitude - end.longitude);

    double dis = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(lat, 2) + Math.pow(lng, 2));
    if(dis >= animateDistance) {
        double angle = -1;

        if(begin.latitude <= end.latitude && begin.longitude <= end.longitude)
            angle = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng / lat));
        else if(begin.latitude > end.latitude && begin.longitude <= end.longitude)
            angle = (90 - Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng / lat))) + 90;
        else if(begin.latitude > end.latitude && begin.longitude > end.longitude)
            angle = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng / lat)) + 180;
        else if(begin.latitude <= end.latitude && begin.longitude > end.longitude)
            angle = (90 - Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng / lat))) + 270;

        double x = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle)) * animateDistance;
        double y = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle)) * animateDistance;
        totalAnimateDistance += animateDistance;
        double finalLat = begin.latitude + x;
        double finalLng = begin.longitude + y;

        return new LatLng(finalLat, finalLng);
    } else {
        return end;
    }
}

private float getBearing(LatLng begin, LatLng end) {
    double lat = Math.abs(begin.latitude - end.latitude); 
    double lng = Math.abs(begin.longitude - end.longitude);
     if(begin.latitude < end.latitude && begin.longitude < end.longitude)
        return (float)(Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng / lat)));
    else if(begin.latitude >= end.latitude && begin.longitude < end.longitude)
        return (float)((90 - Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng / lat))) + 90);
    else if(begin.latitude >= end.latitude && begin.longitude >= end.longitude)
        return  (float)(Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng / lat)) + 180);
    else if(begin.latitude < end.latitude && begin.longitude >= end.longitude)
        return (float)((90 - Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng / lat))) + 270);
     return -1;
}

public void setCameraUpdateSpeed(int speed) {       
    if(speed == SPEED_VERY_SLOW) {
        animateDistance = 0.000005;
        animateSpeed = 20;
        animateCamera = 0.0004;
        zoom = 19;
    } else if(speed == SPEED_SLOW) {
        animateDistance = 0.00001;
        animateSpeed = 20;
        animateCamera = 0.0008;
        zoom = 18;
    } else if(speed == SPEED_NORMAL) {
        animateDistance = 0.00005;
        animateSpeed = 20;
        animateCamera = 0.002;
        zoom = 16;
    } else if(speed == SPEED_FAST) {
        animateDistance = 0.0001;
        animateSpeed = 20;
        animateCamera = 0.004;
        zoom = 15;
    } else if(speed == SPEED_VERY_FAST) {
        animateDistance = 0.0005;
        animateSpeed = 20;
        animateCamera = 0.004;
        zoom = 13;
    } else {
        animateDistance = 0.00005;
        animateSpeed = 20;
        animateCamera = 0.002;
        zoom = 16;
    }
}
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);


    gd = new GoogleDirection(this);
    gd.setOnDirectionResponseListener(new OnDirectionResponseListener() {
        public void onResponse(String status, Document doc, GoogleDirection gd) {
            mDoc = doc;
        polyline =  mGoogleMap.addPolyline(gd.getPolyline(doc, 10, Color.RED)); 

          }
    });

route.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            LatLng newLatLong1 = new LatLng(la1d, lo1d);
            LatLng newLatLong2 = new LatLng(la2d, lo2d);

            gd.setLogging(true);
            gd.request(newLatLong2, newLatLong1, GoogleDirection.MODE_DRIVING);


    }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `Google Directions API`. Just hit the given URL using HTTP request and get json response. This Google service calculates direction between given locations.

Sample code:

PathGoogleMapActivity.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

public class PathGoogleMapActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private static final LatLng LOWER_MANHATTAN = new LatLng(40.722543,
            -73.998585);
    private static final LatLng BROOKLYN_BRIDGE = new LatLng(40.7057, -73.9964);
    private static final LatLng WALL_STREET = new LatLng(40.7064, -74.0094);

    GoogleMap googleMap;
    final String TAG = "PathGoogleMapActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_path_google_map);
        SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        googleMap = fm.getMap();

        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
        options.position(LOWER_MANHATTAN);
        options.position(BROOKLYN_BRIDGE);
        options.position(WALL_STREET);
        googleMap.addMarker(options);
        String url = getMapsApiDirectionsUrl();
        ReadTask downloadTask = new ReadTask();
        downloadTask.execute(url);

        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(BROOKLYN_BRIDGE,
                13));
        addMarkers();

    }

    private String getMapsApiDirectionsUrl() {
        String waypoints = "waypoints=optimize:true|"
                + LOWER_MANHATTAN.latitude + "," + LOWER_MANHATTAN.longitude
                + "|" + "|" + BROOKLYN_BRIDGE.latitude + ","
                + BROOKLYN_BRIDGE.longitude + "|" + WALL_STREET.latitude + ","
                + WALL_STREET.longitude;

        String sensor = "sensor=false";
        String params = waypoints + "&" + sensor;
        String output = "json";
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"
                + output + "?" + params;
        return url;
    }

    private void addMarkers() {
        if (googleMap != null) {
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(BROOKLYN_BRIDGE)
                    .title("First Point"));
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(LOWER_MANHATTAN)
                    .title("Second Point"));
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(WALL_STREET)
                    .title("Third Point"));
        }
    }

    private class ReadTask extends AsyncTask {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
            String data = "";
            try {
                HttpConnection http = new HttpConnection();
                data = http.readUrl(url[0]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            new ParserTask().execute(result);
        }
    }

    private class ParserTask extends
            AsyncTask>>> {

        @Override
        protected List>> doInBackground(
                String... jsonData) {

            JSONObject jObject;
            List>> routes = null;

            try {
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
                PathJSONParser parser = new PathJSONParser();
                routes = parser.parse(jObject);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return routes;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List>> routes) {
            ArrayList points = null;
            PolylineOptions polyLineOptions = null;

            // traversing through routes
            for (int i = 0; i < routes.size(); i++) {
                points = new ArrayList();
                polyLineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
                List> path = routes.get(i);

                for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
                    HashMap point = path.get(j);

                    double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                    double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                    LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                    points.add(position);
                }

                polyLineOptions.addAll(points);
                polyLineOptions.width(2);
                polyLineOptions.color(Color.BLUE);
            }

            googleMap.addPolyline(polyLineOptions);
        }
    }
}
```

HttpConnection.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import android.util.Log;

public class HttpConnection {
    public String readUrl(String mapsApiDirectionsUrl) throws IOException {
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(mapsApiDirectionsUrl);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.connect();
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    iStream));
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            data = sb.toString();
            br.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Exception while reading url", e.toString());
        } finally {
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return data;
    }

}
```

PathJSONParser.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

public class PathJSONParser {

    public List>> parse(JSONObject jObject) {
        List>> routes = new ArrayList>>();
        JSONArray jRoutes = null;
        JSONArray jLegs = null;
        JSONArray jSteps = null;
        try {
            jRoutes = jObject.getJSONArray("routes");
            /** Traversing all routes */
            for (int i = 0; i < jRoutes.length(); i++) {
                jLegs = ((JSONObject) jRoutes.get(i)).getJSONArray("legs");
                List> path = new ArrayList>();

                /** Traversing all legs */
                for (int j = 0; j < jLegs.length(); j++) {
                    jSteps = ((JSONObject) jLegs.get(j)).getJSONArray("steps");

                    /** Traversing all steps */
                    for (int k = 0; k < jSteps.length(); k++) {
                        String polyline = "";
                        polyline = (String) ((JSONObject) ((JSONObject) jSteps
                                .get(k)).get("polyline")).get("points");
                        List list = decodePoly(polyline);

                        /** Traversing all points */
                        for (int l = 0; l < list.size(); l++) {
                            HashMap hm = new HashMap();
                            hm.put("lat",
                                    Double.toString(((LatLng) list.get(l)).latitude));
                            hm.put("lng",
                                    Double.toString(((LatLng) list.get(l)).longitude));
                            path.add(hm);
                        }
                    }
                    routes.add(path);
                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return routes;
    }

    /**
     * Method Courtesy :
     * jeffreysambells.com/2010/05/27
     * /decoding-polylines-from-google-maps-direction-api-with-java
     * */
    private List decodePoly(String encoded) {

        List poly = new ArrayList();
        int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;

        while (index < len) {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;

            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                    (((double) lng / 1E5)));
            poly.add(p);
        }
        return poly;
    }
}
```

For more details, please refer [here](http://javapapers.com/android/draw-path-on-google-maps-android-api/).